# SQL Pivot dynamic query error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried to convert rows values into columns...Below is my query...

```
Select * from (SELECT  *
            FROM    (   SELECT PROJ.PROJ_ID,
                               PROJ.PROJ_NM AS [Project Name],
                               PROJ.PROJ_DS AS [Project Description],
                               convert(varchar(10), PROJ.PROJ_ACTL_LNCH_DT, 110) [Actual Completed Date],
                               PROJ.PROJ_SMRY_DS AS [Project Summary],
                               dbo.udf_BankContacts(PROJ.PROJ_ID) AS [BankContact],  
                               convert(varchar(10), PROJ.PROJ_EST_LNCH_DT, 110) AS [Estimated Launch Date],
                               PROJ.ENTER_DT AS [Begin Date],
                               PROJ_STA.PROJ_STA_DS AS [Project Status],
                               SFTW_DEV_MTHD.SFTW_DEV_MTHD_NM AS [Software Development Method],
                               PROJ_PHASE.PROJ_PHASE_DS AS [Phase],
                               PROJ_CTGY.PROJ_CTGY_DS AS [Project Category],
                               (CASE  WHEN PROJ.ARCH_IN='0' THEN 'N' ELSE 'C' END) AS [Archive],
                               PROJ.PHASE_CMNT_TX AS [Phase Comment],
                               PROD_TYPE_DS

                        FROM  dbo.Project PROJ  
                         left join dbo.PROJ_PROD  PP on PROJ.PROJ_ID = PP.PROJ_ID
                         left join dbo.PROD_TYPE PT on PP.PROD_TYPE_ID = PT.PROD_TYPE_ID
                         LEFT JOIN DBO.PROJ_STA ON PROJ.PROJ_STA_ID = PROJ_STA.PROJ_STA_ID
                         left join dbo.SFTW_DEV_MTHD on PROJ.SFTW_DEV_MTHD_ID = SFTW_DEV_MTHD.SFTW_DEV_MTHD_ID
                         left join dbo.PROJ_PHASE on PROJ.PROJ_PHASE_ID = PROJ_PHASE.PROJ_PHASE_ID
                         left join dbo.PROJ_CTGY on PROJ.PROJ_CTGY_ID = PROJ_CTGY.PROJ_CTGY_ID
                    ) data

                    PIVOT
                    (   MAX(PROD_TYPE_DS)
                        FOR PROD_TYPE_DS IN ([PT1],[PT2])
                    ) pvt2

                    where PROJ_ID is not null) AS  ProdType
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  *
            FROM    
            (   
              select PROJ_ID,
                PROJ_APRV_TYPE_DS = case 
                            when col ='PROJ_APRV_TYPE_DS' 
                            then PROJ_APRV_TYPE_DS 
                            else PROJ_APRV_TYPE_DS+col end,
                value
              from
              (
                 SELECT PROJ.PROJ_ID,

                   PAT.PROJ_APRV_TYPE_DS PROJ_APRV_TYPE_DS,
                   convert(varchar(10), PATS.APRV_EXPT_BY_DT, 120) APRV_EXPT_BY_DT, 
                   convert(varchar(10), PATS.APRV_CMPL_DT, 120) APRV_CMPL_DT                   
                 FROM  dbo.Project PROJ  
                 left join [dbo].[PROJ_APRV_TYPE_STA] PATS 
                    on PROJ.PROJ_ID = PATS.PROJ_ID
                 left join   [dbo].[PROJ_APRV_STA] PAS
                    on PATS.PROJ_APRV_STA_ID = PAS.PROJ_APRV_STA_ID
                 right outer join dbo.PROJ_APRV_TYPE PAT 
                    on PATS.PROJ_APRV_TYPE_ID = PAT.PROJ_APRV_TYPE_ID
               ) s
               cross apply
               (
                  select 'PROJ_APRV_TYPE_DS', PROJ_APRV_TYPE_DS union all
                  select ' Expected Date', APRV_EXPT_BY_DT union all
                  select ' Completed Date', APRV_CMPL_DT
               ) c (col, value)
           ) data
           PIVOT
           (   
              MAX(value)
              FOR PROJ_APRV_TYPE_DS IN ([RMC Approval],[RMC Approval Expected Date],[RMC Approval Completed Date],[BOD Approval],[BOD Approval Expected Date],[BOD Approval Completed Date]) 
           ) pvt1 where PROJ_ID is not null ) AS Approval ON ProdType.PROJ_ID = Approval.PROJ_ID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  *
            FROM    (   SELECT PROJ.PROJ_ID,
                                ORG_SHRT_NM                                
                        FROM  dbo.Project PROJ  
                         left join dbo.PROJ_LGL_ENT_IMPCT  PLEI on PROJ.PROJ_ID = PLEI.PROJ_ID
                         right outer join dbo.LGL_ENT LE on PLEI.LGL_ENT_ID = LE.LGL_ENT_ID
                    ) data

                     PIVOT
                    (   MAX(ORG_SHRT_NM)
                        FOR ORG_SHRT_NM IN ([AECB],[FSB],[TRS])
                    ) pvt3

                    where PROJ_ID is not null) AS LegalEntity ON ProdType.PROJ_ID = LegalEntity.PROJ_ID  LEFT JOIN 

                    (;with cte as 
                    (
          SELECT PCGU.PROJ_ID,
            name = u.USER_LST_NM + ', '+ u.USER_FIRST_NM,           
            CTC_GRP_DS                               
          FROM  dbo.[user] u  
          left join dbo.PROJ_CTC_GRP_USER  PCGU 
            on u.USER_ID = PCGU.USER_ID
          left join dbo.CTC_GRP CG 
            on PCGU.CTC_GRP_ID = CG.CTC_GRP_ID
        ) 
        select *
        from
        (
          select c1.proj_id,
            c1.CTC_GRP_DS,
            STUFF(
                 (SELECT ', ' + c2.name
                  FROM cte c2
                  where c1.proj_id = c2.proj_id
                    and c1.CTC_GRP_DS = c2.CTC_GRP_DS
                  FOR XML PATH (''))
                  , 1, 1, '')  AS name
          from cte c1
        ) d     

        pivot
        (
          max(name)
          for CTC_GRP_DS in ([Bank Contact],[Dept2])
        ) piv 
        where PROJ_ID is not null) 
        AS Dept ON ProdType.PROJ_ID = Dept.PROJ_ID
```

I am getting error 
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 84
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 115
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I am totally confused what i am missing it. I recently started pivot & dynamic query concepts...Please guide on it...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here.

```
                (;with cte as 
                (
      SELECT PCGU.PROJ_ID,
        name = u.USER_LST_NM + ', '+ u.USER_FIRST_NM,           
        CTC_GRP_DS                               
      FROM  dbo.[user] u  
      left join dbo.PROJ_CTC_GRP_USER  PCGU 
        on u.USER_ID = PCGU.USER_ID
      left join dbo.CTC_GRP CG 
        on PCGU.CTC_GRP_ID = CG.CTC_GRP_ID
    ) 
    select *
    from
    (
      select c1.proj_id,
        c1.CTC_GRP_DS,
        STUFF(
             (SELECT ', ' + c2.name
              FROM cte c2
              where c1.proj_id = c2.proj_id
                and c1.CTC_GRP_DS = c2.CTC_GRP_DS
              FOR XML PATH (''))
              , 1, 1, '')  AS name
      from cte c1
    ) d
```

You cannot have a CTE in sub selects like that.

You could try to put the CTE at the very top, or create a temp table for the select.

Comment: Do you have any idea to export the result set into temp table? I mean result set from above query?

Answer (score 0):

The error is with your CTE. You can't stick a CTE inside a query like that

```
(;with cte as
```